# Long live X - what type of word is 'live'?

Tags: word-usage

> Long live Egypt.
>   Long live the king.

I want to know whether (live) here is a verb or a noun or an adjective.

Comment: *Live* is never a noun.   You may not have heard this phrase spoken out loud, but since the adjective is pronounced LYE-v and in this phrase the word is pronounced LIHV, it can only be a verb.

Answer (score 3):

***[Long live someone/something](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/long-live-someone-something)*** is a fixed phrase:

> - used for expressing your support for or loyalty to someone or something.
>     *He was greeted with chants of ‘Long live the king!’*

Live here is a verb used in the subjunctive mood.